# Why the second scanf also changes the variate presented in the first scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I want to input an integer number and a character with scanf funtion, but it didn't work as I want.

The codes are as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    char c;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%2c",&c);
    printf("%d%c",a,c);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to input `12a`  (there is a space after `a`) from the terminal, but the output is not "12a" but "32a".

I also tried to run the code above step by step and found that when it run into the first "scanf", the value of "a" is 12, but when run into second "scanf", the value of "a" turned 32.

I want to figure out why the second `scanf` changes the value of `a`, which is not presented.

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf()` to see if it was successful.

Comment: You are trying to read two symbols into single `char` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler has put variable `a` just behind variable `c`.  When you do the second `scanf()` you specify to read **two characters** into a variable that has space only for one.  You have incurred in a buffer overflow, and have overwritten memory past the variable `c` (and `a` happens to be there).  The space has been written into `a` and this is the reason that you get `32` output (`a` has been stored the value of an ASCII SPACE, wich is 32).

What has happened is known as Undefined Behaviour, and it's common when you make this kind of mistakes.  You can solve this by definning an array of `char` cells with at least two cells for reading the two characters .  and then use something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    char c[2];
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%2c", c);   /* now c is a char array so don't use & */
    printf("%d%.2s", a, c); /* use %.2s format instead */
    return 0;
}
```

### Note:

the use of `%.2s` format specifier is due to the fact that `c` is an array of two chars that has been filled completely (without allowing space to include a `\0` string end delimiter)  this would cause undefined behaviour if we don't ensure that the formatting will end at the second character (or before, in case a true `\0` is found in the first or the second array positions)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting `C11`, chapter 7.21.6.2, The `fscanf` function (*emphasis mine*)

> `c`
>
> *[...]If an `l` length modifier is present, the input shall be a sequence of multibyte characters that begins in the initial shift state. Each multibyte character in the sequence is converted to a wide character as if by a call to the `mbrtowc` function, with the conversion state described by an `mbstate_t` object initialized to zero before the first multibyte character is converted. **The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of `wchar_t` large enough to accept the resulting sequence of wide characters.** [...]*

and you're supplying a `char *`. The supplied argument does not match the expected type of argument, so this is undefined behavior.

Therefore the outcome cannot be justified.

To hold an input like `"a "`, you'll need a (long enough) `char` array, a `char` variable is not sufficient.

Comment: You quoted the text for `%lc`

Comment: Is that the reason why scanf is not safe? It seems do not check whether it has accessed an improper place.

Comment: @Sirly C does not check at all that targets like an array are big enough. This is a compromise for speed and size, and is historically. Not only `scanf()` is unsafe, a lot of other standard functions too, and any function you will write yourself if you don't implement counter measures..